# Installing Android NDK r10d for Travis CI

Tags: android-ndk, travis-ci

What should I put in my .travis.yml file to install Android NDK r10d?

I'm intermittently getting a `failed and exited with 137` failure from Travis on the last line here:

```
# Get Android NDK
- if [ `uname -m` = x86_64]; then wget http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10d-linux-x86_64.bin -O ndk.bin; else wget http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r10d-linux-x86.bin -O ndk.bin; fi
- chmod a+x ndk.bin
- ./ndk.bin 1> /dev/null 2>&1
```

I don't think this mysterious error 137 is due to a timeout, because the error is thrown after spending only about a minute on the last line.

If I change this code to not redirect the output to /dev/null, Travis again fails because running the .bin file prints more than 10k lines to the log.

Comment: Is there any chance the travis instance runs on a x86_32 installation?

Comment: That's a good question. I wouldn't expect that to affect the extraction, but it's worth checking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the `137` error indicates that the virtual machine has run out of memory. There's not necessarily anything wrong with the script itself.

Two things that are worth trying to avoid the `137` error:

- According to [this thread](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/3416), you can try running on containers, which have more memory available
- According to [this thread](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4192), you can try increasing your system stack size with

  > ```
  > ulimit -s 1082768
  > ```

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-dev/oom-killer-1911807.html

Answer (score -1):

I was able to successfully extract and run the ndk by answering yes to all questions and ignoring output that said "Extracting"

```
  - ./ndk.bin -y | grep -v Extracting
```